# Removing "from" in WP eCommerce

Tags: php, string, wordpress, e-commerce

In the product page listing on Wordpress' eCommerce plugin, the prices are listed as "from.." no matter if there's only one price. This gives a bad impression to the customer because it signals that the price will probably be above what is listed.

I have searched for this "from" in both the PHP files and language files but haven't found it. Do any of you know where it is?

Comment: Tangent, but don't use WP eCommerce. Speaking from experience, it's one of the most difficult WP plugins I've dealt with. Unless you are attached to it, use Cart 66 or something else that fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.8.9 release of WP e-Commerce includes a filter for replacing/removing the 'from' element, update safe fix.

```
$from_text = __( ' from %s', 'wpsc' );
$from_text = apply_filters( 'wpsc_product_variation_text', $from_text );
```

Line #436 of product-template.php in 3.8.9

...

```
function wpsc_remove_variation_text( $from_text ) {
$from_text = '%s';
return $from_text;
}
add_filter( 'wpsc_product_variation_text', 'wpsc_remove_variation_text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line in your **product-template.php** file line **416**

```
//$output = sprintf(__(' from %s', 'wpsc'), $output);
```

File can be found at

```
wp-content\plugins\wp-e-commerce\wpsc-includes\
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You go to line 416 of the **product-template.php** in

> wp-content\plugins\wp-e-commerce\wpsc-includes\

However, instead of commenting out the entire line, like styks1987 suggested, you just remove the part that says ' from '.

If you remove the entire line,  then if the product comes in one size and the variations are thus not ticked, it does not show a price at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to functions.php file that is inside your currently active theme folder:

```
function wpsc_remove_variation_text( $from_text ) {
    $from_text = '%s';
    return $from_text;
}
add_filter( 'wpsc_product_variation_text', 'wpsc_remove_variation_text' );
```